# Do you say "Ich lerne gerne neue sache?"

Tags: english-to-german

How do you say "I like to learn new things?" in german. Do you say "Ich lerne gern neue sache" or "ich lerne gern neue dinge? Or something else?

Answer (score 8):

I am not a native German speaker, but I grew up learning the language.

I would say "Ich lerne gerne neue Dinge". If you would like to say " I would like to learn new things." I would say "Ich möchte gerne neue Dinge lernen."
Both "Sachen" and "Dinge" are correct.

When you are going to write it, do not forget the capital "D"/"S" in "Dinge" or "Sachen".

I hope this helps you.

Els

Comment: You almost got it right. :) Only the plural of *Ding* is *Dinge*. Without the *n*.

Comment: Thank you! Always happy to learn new things :-).

Answer (score 7):

The plural of "Sache" is "Sachen".

But apart from that, yes you can say

> "Ich lerne gern neue Sachen."

Another similar phrase you can use:

> "Ich bin offen für Neues"

which focuses more on *experiencing* new stuff, rather than learning them.

Answer (score 4):

What a German would say is:

> Ich lerne gerne Neues.